# Knockout - display element if date is greater than

Tags: knockout.js

I want to display something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'https://scyk.pl/Account/UserProfile?user=' + peer}, text: peer"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but I want this whole `tr` element to be displayed only if `date` (property of my model) is greater than `(current date-15min)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `tr` element in a [virtual element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) that uses the [if](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding:

```
<!-- ko if: date().getTime() > new Date().getTime() - 900000 -->
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The above works, but the expression that does the date calculation should really be part of the view model. A cleaner way is to add a computed to your view model:

```
model.isDateAfterFifteenMinutesAgo = ko.computed(function () {
    return model.date().getTime() > new Date().getTime() - 900000;
});
```

And then use `<!-- ko if: isDateAfterFifteenMinutesAgo -->` in your HTML.

Comment: Please, start using the ViewModel. Its there for a reason

Comment: Edited to suggest using the view model.